# Confusion about the common eigenvalues of ket and bra vectors

Tags: notation, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics, eigenfunctions

As far as I understand, for linear operators on bra vectors,

> Let $H = L_2 (\mathbb{R})$, and $\phi \in H^*$ and $f \in H$ be
>   arbitrary, and let $\alpha : H \to H$ be a linear map.
>
> Then for any $\alpha$, we have an induced dual map $\alpha^*: H^* \to H^*$
>   such that
>
> $$\langle\phi, \alpha (f) \rangle = \langle\alpha^* (\phi), f\rangle \quad \forall \phi \in H^*, \forall f \in H,$$ where $\langle,\rangle$ is the
>   non-degenerate bilinear map between $H$ and $H^*$.

However, the quote from Dirac's book on Quantum Mechanic:

> "*ii)* The eigenvalues associated with eigenkets are the same as the
>   eigenvalues associated with eigenbras.
>
> *iii)* The conjugate imaginary (dual map) of any eigenket is an eigenbra belonging to the same eigenvalue, and conversely."

and with the above definition that I gave, I get the following result:

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue associated with $f$ of $\alpha$.Then we have

$$\langle\alpha^* (\phi), f\rangle = \langle\phi, \alpha (f) \rangle = \langle\phi, \lambda f\rangle \Rightarrow \\ 
\langle\alpha^* (\phi), f\rangle = \langle\phi, \lambda f\rangle = \langle\lambda \phi, f\rangle \Rightarrow \\
\alpha^* (\phi) = \lambda \phi \quad \forall \phi \in H^*$$

Even though, this result does not conflict with the first condition that Dirac gave, it conflicts with the second one because with this result, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $\psi$ which is the corresponding bra vector of the ket $g$, then g has also have the eigenvalue $\lambda$, and since $\psi$ is arbitrary, $\alpha$ cannot have more than one eigenvalue on $H$.

So my question is that is there any flow in my derivation and the above definition, (I mean there should be), if not, what am I missing ?

**Edit:**

We consider $H = L_2 (\mathbb{R})$ as a complex vector space.

**Edit 2:**

The bilinear form $$\langle \psi, f\rangle = (g, f) = \int \bar g f dx,$$
where $\psi$ is the eigenket of $g$, and $(,)$ is the inner product defined on $H$.

**Edit 3:**

I have realised my mistake, which is after the line $$ \langle\alpha^* (\phi), f\rangle = \langle\phi, \lambda f\rangle = \langle\lambda \phi, f\rangle $$
because f is not arbitrary, it is fixed according to $\lambda$, so we cannot assume the next step, and we are left with

$$<\alpha^* (\phi) - \lambda \phi, f > = 0.$$

**But, now how can we derive what Dirac says ?**

Comment: Are we considering $H$ as complex or real vector space?

Comment: @Roland it is complex.

Comment: How does the map $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ look like, in this case? I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around how that mapping works, since $(f,g) \mapsto = \int f \overline g$ is sesquilinear (and getting rid of the conjugate would make it degenerate).

Comment: @Roland See my edit 2.